# What will be displayed by the MessageBox?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I Have Code for EventHandler like this below.

I do not know what is meant by **e.Value**, can someone explain and show approximately what will be displayed by the MessageBox?

```
    void ConnectionManager_Error(object sender, EventArgs<string> e)
    {
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            State = ConnectState.NotFound;
            MessageBox.Show(e.Value);
        });
    }
```

**Note:**

I have this code that I thought would trigger ConnectionManager Error EventHandler.

```
private void LogError(string error)
{
    if (Error != null)
        Error(this, new EventArgs<string>(error));
}
```

I also have this code that gives an error message containing the string  to LogError method.

```
int lasterror = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (lasterror != 0)
                    LogError("Bluetooth API returned: " + lasterror.ToString());
```

or

```
 if (BluetoothSetServiceState(IntPtr.Zero, ref device, ref HumanInterfaceDeviceServiceClass_UUID, BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_ENABLE) != 0)
                                LogError("Failed to connect to wiimote controller");
```

**Another Hint**

To be more specific, I also already have the code below:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs<string>> Error;
```

and

```
ConnectionManager.Error += new EventHandler<EventArgs<string>>(ConnectionManager_Error);
```

And also this class:

```
public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
    {
        public T Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public EventArgs(T value)
            : base()
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

But MessageBox never appears even when the device is not connected to the computer. 
I think that comes MassageBox supposed that show error messages. 
Can someone show me what is wrong?

Comment: Why not just run it and find out?

Comment: Because when I execute the whole solution, the MessageBox does not appear on the screen even when the device is not connected.
Supposedly raises the error message displays the error that occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ConnectionManager` has `Error` event, which passes instance of `EventArgs<string>` to event handlers. I believe generic event argument looks like:

```
public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public EventArgs(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; private set; }
}
```

So, `ConnectionManager` sets some string value to this argument of event and passes it to `ConnectionManager_Error` event handler. You should see value which was passed. From event name I can assume it should be error message.

NOTE: `ConnectState` enum, `State` property of `ConnectionManager` and its `StateChanged` event is not related to code you work with.

Answer (score 0):

A Message Box is shown with the value provided by the EventArgs. I can only assume that your EventArgs class is a generic EventArgs implementation where the type parameters defines the type of the value.

So whatever the value is, that is what you will see in the MessageBox.